# How can I pass and receive data to/from an ngx-bootstrap modal?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Passing data to a modal can be done using the [initialState](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals), but how can I receive data back? For instance, if I want to create a confirm dialog box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though there's currently no built-in way to do that, it can be done by binding to the onHide/onHidden events.

The idea is to create an Observer that will subscribe to the onHidden event and fire `next()` when it receives data from it.

I'm using the onHidden instead of the onHide so all CSS animations are done before the result is returned.

Also I implemented it in a `MessageService` to keep a better separation of the code.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

    constructor(
        private bsModalService: BsModalService,
    ) { }

    confirm(title: string, message: string, options: string[]): Observable<string> {
        const initialState = {
            title: title,
            message: message,
            options: options,
        };
        this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(ConfirmDialogComponent, { initialState });

        return new Observable<string>(this.getConfirmSubscriber());
    }

    private getConfirmSubscriber() {
        return (observer) => {
            const subscription = this.bsModalService.onHidden.subscribe((reason: string) => {
                observer.next(this.bsModalRef.content.answer);
                observer.complete();
            });

            return {
                unsubscribe() {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The ConfirmDialogComponent looks like this:

```js
export class ConfirmDialogComponent {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    options: string[];
    answer: string = "";

    constructor(
        public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    ) { }

    respond(answer: string) {
        this.answer = answer;

        this.bsModalRef.hide();
    }

}
```

After implemented, using it is very straight-forward:

```js
confirm() {
    this.messageService
        .confirm(
            "Confirmation dialog box",
            "Are you sure you want to proceed?",
            ["Yes", "No"])
        .subscribe((answer) => {
            this.answers.push(answer);
        });
}
```

You can get the full code and see it running in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhbsa9).

Comment: Problem with this approach is, that it only works as long as the modal-component is in the `entryComponents` of your `NgModule` which also provides the message service.